# Separate numeric inside string variable using patindex

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have here a short problem.

i have a value like this

`1/11`
`11/1`
`11/11`
`111/1`
`111/11`

i'm trying to separate those value and put them into numeric variable. 
let say for example i have `numericvar1` and `numericvar2`

so in the 1st string `numericvar1` will contain 1 and `numericvar2` will contain 11

and so on.

i've tried it like this

```
SET @numericvar1= LEFT(@StrNumHolder, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @StrNumHolder ))
SET @numericvar2= REPLACE(RIGHT(@StrNumHolder, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @StrNumHolder )),'/','')
```

in this code if the first number before `/` is in 2 digit i got the correct output. But if the first number is in 1 digit and the next number is in 2 digit like `1/11` i got the wrong output. something like this `var1 = 1` and `var2 = 1`

did something wrong in my code? or it is not possible? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this?

```
DECLARE @STRNUMHOLDER VARCHAR(20)
SET @STRNUMHOLDER='111/1'
DECLARE @pos INT
SET @pos = CHARINDEX('/', @STRNUMHOLDER)
SELECT @STRNUMHOLDER AS ORIG, LEFT(@STRNUMHOLDER, @pos-1) AS NUM1, SUBSTRING(@STRNUMHOLDER, @pos+1,99) AS NUM2
```

Comment: i tried it and change some sort of code to reach my goal. hehe. tnx anyway i think i can use this. `SET @pos = CHARINDEX('/', @STRNUMHOLDER)` this will indicate me where the `'/'` is located so in your select i modified it to become like this `SELECT @STRNUMHOLDER AS ORIG, LEFT(@STRNUMHOLDER, @pos-1) AS NUM1, SUBSTRING(@STRNUMHOLDER, @pos+1,99) AS NUM2`

Comment: I made a type error while making a correction (I inverted + and -)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CHARINDEX to get the position of '/' then use SUBSTRING to separate the numbers. Here how you can query it:

```
DECLARE @nIndex INT
SELECT @nIndex = CHARINDEX('/',@StrNumHolder)

SET @numericvar1 = SELECT SUBSTRING(@StrNumHolder,1,@nIndex-1)
SET @numericvar2 = SELECT SUBSTRING(@StrNumHolder,@nIndex+1,LEN(@StrNumHolder))
```